# VirtualBox (5.2) installation issue / guest additions for metasploitable3

Tags: apt, kali-linux, virtualbox, vagrant, metasploit

I am having issues installing virtualbox on my kali-rolling dist (Linux kali 4.12.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.12.6-1kali6 (2017-08-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux).

My main goal is to setup metasploitable3 (https://github.com/rapid7/metasploitable3).

I have installed packer and vagrant:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/metasploitable3# packer -v
1.1.3
root@kali:~/Desktop/metasploitable3# vagrant -v
Vagrant 2.0.1
```

I have purged vitualbox and reinstalled for the sake of demonstration:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/metasploitable3# sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') virtualbox dkms virtualbox-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-headers-amd64 is already the newest version (4.14+89+kali1).
Suggested packages:
  python3-apport vde2 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 273 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/26.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 111 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 343278 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/dkms_2.3-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.3-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-dkms_5.2.6-dfsg-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (5.2.6-dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox_5.2.6-dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox (5.2.6-dfsg-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-qt.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-qt_5.2.6-dfsg-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-qt (5.2.6-dfsg-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-2) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47+b1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.3-3) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (236-3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-4) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-1) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (5.2.6-dfsg-2) ...
Loading new virtualbox-5.2.6 DKMS files...
Building for 4.12.0-kali1-amd64
Module build for kernel 4.12.0-kali1-amd64 was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Setting up virtualbox (5.2.6-dfsg-2) ...
vboxweb.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-01-31 10:15:25 CST; 7ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 22278 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 31 10:15:25 kali systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Jan 31 10:15:25 kali virtualbox[22278]: Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...No suitable module for running kernel found ... failed!
Jan 31 10:15:25 kali virtualbox[22278]:  failed!
Jan 31 10:15:25 kali systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 31 10:15:25 kali systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 31 10:15:25 kali systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Setting up virtualbox-qt (5.2.6-dfsg-2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (236-3) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47+b1) ...
```

After this, I am capable of running the virtualbox GUI. But when I want to execute the metasploitable3 build script I get the following error:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/metasploitable3# ./build_win2008.sh
./build_win2008.sh: line 14: cha: command not found
./build_win2008.sh: line 27: [[: WARNING:: syntax error in expression (error token is ":")
./build_win2008.sh: line 31: [[: WARNING:: syntax error in expression (error token is ":")
Compatible version of VirtualBox found.
Compatible version of packer was found.
Correct version of vagrant was found.
Compatible version of vagrant-reload plugin was found.
All requirements found. Proceeding...
Building the Vagrant box...
virtualbox-iso output will be in this color.

Build 'virtualbox-iso' errored: Error reading version for guest additions download: VirtualBox is not properly setup: WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-amd64.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.2.6_Debianr120293

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> virtualbox-iso: Error reading version for guest additions download: VirtualBox is not properly setup: WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-amd64.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.2.6_Debianr120293

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
Error building the Vagrant box using Packer. Please check the output above for any error messages.Error reading version for guest additions download: VirtualBox is not properly setup: WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
 Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
 headers, most likely linux-headers-amd64.

 You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed. 5.2.6_Debianr120293
```

More specifically:

```
Error reading version for guest additions download: VirtualBox is not properly setup: WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-amd64.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.2.6_Debianr120293
```

It seems that an error in my install has caused an error later on with virtualbox-dkms. I have found other issues similar to this, but no fixes have worked.

Thanks.

Comment: I see that there are [build issues](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploitable3) using versions of vagrant newer than 1.9.1 and you are using 2.0.1. Did you try downgrading vagrant?

Comment: I just tried the same process (reinstalled virtualbox) with 1.9.1 but unfortunately it get the same errors.

Comment: Do you have `guest additions` installed in your virtualbox?

Comment: Guest additions are not relevant, as the problem is in running the VirtualBox *host*.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this on my machine.

You need to download and install

```
virtual-guest-add 5.2.6-1 (current version in the rolling repo)
```

which `packer` expects to find in

```
/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
```

To save waiting for the script, you can also download the iso from

```
http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/5/E/75EC4E54-5B02-42D6-8879-D8D3A25FBEF7/7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso
```

which `packer` looks for in

```
whereverYouPutIt/metasploitable3/iso/
```

...... that's as far as i have got so far (waiting for the iso) but grabbing guest additions should cure your immediate problem.

**EDIT**

As you are running `virtualbox 5.2` you will probably need to make [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/9090) adjustment to the configuration files.

In the build I made yesterday I also had to make [this](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploitable3/issues/91) adjustment as the `wamp.bat` current script cloned from the `git` repository points to a dead wamp link and causes the build to fail.

I also had to explicitly add the `.box` file to vagrant

```
vagrant box add -f metasploitable3 /path/to/build/metasploitable3/windows_2008_r2_virtualbox.box
vagrant up
```

This worked witj

```
virtualbox 5.2.6
$packer -v
1.0.4
$vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.9.1
$ uname -a
Linux kali 4.13.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.13.13-1kali1 (2017-11-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Loading new virtualbox-5.2.6 DKMS files...
Building for 4.12.0-kali1-amd64
Module build for kernel 4.12.0-kali1-amd64 was skipped since the
kernel headers for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
```

and later:

```
Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
    headers, most likely linux-headers-amd64.
```

So `virtualbox-dkms` is installed, but `linux-headers-amd64` *with a version number exactly matching your running kernel package* is not. Fix that, and then use the `dkms` command to build the virtualbox kernel modules.